# How do $i$ and $\pi$ show up in this result from a Google search?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation, approximation, pi

I am just curious and play a bit here. I googled `(-1e-10)^(-1e-10)` and got
(-1e-10)^(-1e-10) =
$1 - 3.14159266 × 10^{-10} i$

I guess this is some form of approximation to $x^x$ when $x$ approaches $0$. But what does $i$ stand for and how does $\pi$ show up in this?

Note that googling `1e-10^1e-10` simply returns 0.99999999769.

Comment: I would recommend for you to check out complex numbers and complex number algebra. Then the number will make more sense, even though the calculation might not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $r$ is a small positive real, one branch of exponentiation gives$$(-r)^{-r}=(re^{i\pi})^{-r}=\underbrace{r^{-r}}_{\approx1}\underbrace{e^{-ir\pi}}_{\approx1-ir\pi}\approx1-ir\pi.$$

Comment: I saw you jumped through a lot of approximations there, $-1 \approx e^{i\pi}$, $e^{i\theta} \approx cos\theta + i sin\theta$, $cos \epsilon \approx 1$, $sin \epsilon \approx \epsilon$, and change $-sin x$ for $sin -x$. What I found most impressive is the underbrace. Not sure if some approximations are still correct on both side of 0, though the limit of $r^{-r}$ seems to look OK.

Comment: @THN The first two things you called approximations are **exact**. I had $e^z\approx1+z$ in mind rather than the trigonometric examples you gave next; that, together with $\lim_{r\to0^+}r^{-r}=1$, is all I needed in terms of approximation.

Comment: Cool, those two things are exact, their approximations are the same Taylor series. I wonder if there is other approaches, but the trigonometric approximations can also be derived from the first two terms of the Taylor series like what you used. It's was a fun exercise.